# fileTree visit exclude directories

Tags: gradle, groovy

I'm looking for some mechanism that would allow me to execute an action over each file in a directory that matches a certain pattern.

I'm currently trying to make fileTree work this way.

```
def srcDir = 'myDir'
def includePattern = '*'
def tree = fileTree(srcDir) {
    include includePattern
}

tree.visit { d ->
    logger.info(d.file)
}
```

My directory looks like this:

```
myDir/file1
myDir/file2
myDir/subDir/file3
```

What I would like to have as output is:

```
/../myDir/file1
/../myDir/file2
```

But of course `subDir` also matches the `*` include pattern. So it gets included in the result.

How can I only visit files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing I could come up with that will still work with an include pattern (and exclude if needed) is to add an if in the visit closure.

```
def srcDir = 'myDir'
def includePattern = '*'
def tree = fileTree(srcDir) {
    include includePattern
}

tree.visit { d ->
    if (!d.file.isDirectory()) {
        logger.info(d.file)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to do a recursive scan but just scan a single directory, you can do something like [eachFileMatch](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#eachFileMatch(groovy.io.FileType,%20java.lang.Object,%20groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.* 

new File('myDir').eachFileMatch FILES, ~/.*/, { f -> 
  println f.name
}
```

which would print:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy                                                                                          1 ↵
file2
file1
```

where `f` is a [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) and `~/.*/` is a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) matching on file names. `.*` means any character, zero or more times. To match say a `.txt` extension you would do something like `~/.*\.txt/`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
def srcDir = 'myDir'

task go() {
    doFirst {
        new File(srcDir).eachFileRecurse { f ->
            if (f.isFile()) {
                println f.absolutePath.replaceAll("${projectDir}", "/..")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where this is invoked with `gradle go`.